# Proof that a stopped continuous-time martingale is a martingale.

Tags: martingales, stopping-times

The proof for a stopped discrete-time martingale is shown as follows.

> Let $M=(M_n)_{n\ge0}$ be a discrete-time martinglae w.r.t. the filtration $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\ge0}$, and let $M^T=(M_{n\land T})_{n\ge0}$ be the stopped martingale, where $T$ is a stopping time w.r.t. $(\mathcal F_n)_{n\ge0}$. Since:
>
> 1. We have
>      $$\begin{align}
>    M_{n\land T}&=1_{T\ge n+1}M_n+1_{T\le n}M_T\\
>    &=1_{T\ge n+1}M_n+ \sum_{k=1}^n 1_{T=k}M_k\\
>    \end{align}$$
>      where $1_{T\ge n+1}, M_n, 1_{T=k}$, and $M_k$ are all $\mathcal F_n-measurable$, hence $M_{n\land T}$ is $\mathcal F_n-measurable$;
> 2. ${\Bbb E}|M_{n\land T}| \le \underbrace{{\Bbb E}|M_1|+…+{\Bbb E}|M_n|}_{{\Bbb E}|M_i| \text{ is integrable, }\forall i\ge0}<\infty$, i.e., $M_{n\land T}$ is integrable $\forall n \ge 0$;
> 3. We have
>      $$\begin{align}
>    {\Bbb E}(M_{n+1 \land T}|{\mathcal F_n}) &= {\Bbb E}(M_{n \land T}+1_{T \ge n+1}(M_{n+1}-M_n)|{\mathcal F_n})\\
>    &=M_{n \land T}+1_{T \ge n+1}{\Bbb E}(M_{n+1}-M_n)\\
>    &=M_{n \land T}\\
>    \end{align}$$
>
> Therefore, the stopped martingale satisfies the definition of a discrete martingale. Proof complete.

However, I am not able to extend these three parts of proof to a continuous version, because I cannot devide the time into separate spots with one next to another as the discrete version did. So I really wonder how to give a proof for a continuous-time martingale.

Comment: What is preventing you to apply the technique shown in the other answer?

Comment: @Did  I have edited the question. I think the difficulty lies in dealing with the continuity of time.

Comment: With dyadics, page 2 : http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/huiwang/classes/Am264/Archive/Brownian.pdf This idea is to discretize the time, build discrete stopping times on these time slots, and conclude using backward martingales.

Answer (score 4):

We are going to prove the following proposition:

If $M$ is a continuous martingale and $T$ a stopping time, the stopped process $M^{T}$, i.e., $\{M(t \wedge T), t \geq 0\}$ is a martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{F}_{t}\right)$.

Here we go.

The process $M^{T}$ is obviously continuous and adapted.
Firstly we use a weak form of optional stopping theorem, saying that a martingale has equal expectation at any bounded stopping time. If $S$ is a bounded stopping time, so is $S \wedge T$; hence $$ E\left[M_{S}^{T}\right]=E\left[M_{S \wedge T}\right]=E\left[M_{0}\right]=E\left[M_{0}^{T}\right]. $$
    Then we use this conclusion twice to get our desired equality. If $s<t$ and $A \in \mathcal{F}_{s}$ the r.v. $T=t \mathbf{1}_{A^{c}}+s \mathbf{1}_{A}$ is a stopping time and consequently
    $$ E\left[X_{0}\right]=E\left[X_{T}\right]=E\left[X_{t} \mathbf{1}_{A^{c}}\right]+E\left[X_{s} \mathbf{1}_{A}\right] .$$
    On the other hand, $t$ itself is a stopping time, and $$ E\left[X_{0}\right]=E\left[X_{t}\right]=E\left[X_{t} \mathbf{1}_{A^{c}}\right]+E\left[X_{t} \mathbf{1}_{A}\right]. $$

Comparing the two equalities yields $X_{s}=E\left[X_{t} | \mathcal{F}_{s}\right].$

Answer (score 2):

With dyadics, page 2 : http://www.dam.brown.edu/people/huiwang/classes/Am264/Archive/Brownian.pdf. The idea is to discretize the time, build discrete stopping times on these time slots, and conclude using backward martingales.

**Optional sampling theorem** : If $X = (X_t,\mathcal{F}_t)$ is a supermartingale and $T$ is an arbitrary stopping time, then the *stopped process* $X^T=(X_{T\wedge t},\mathcal{F}_t)$ is also a supermartingale.

*Proof* : Here we give a sketch of the proof. Assume $X$ is a supermartingale. First, for a fixed $n\ge 1$, let
$$
D_n = \left\{\frac{k}{2^n}, k= 0,1,2,\ldots\right\}\subset D_{n+1}\subset \cdots
$$
be the set of non-negative dyadic rationals of order no greater than $n$. It follows that
$$
X = (X_t,\mathcal{F}_t; t\in D_n)
$$
is a super martingale (discrete time).

Second, we construct a stopping time $T_n$ such that $T_n\ge T$ and $T_n$ only take values in $D_n$. Indeed, let
$$
T_n(\omega) = \inf\left\{t\in D_n; t\ge T(\omega)\right\}.
$$
Then $T_n\ge T_{n+1} \ge \cdots $ and $T_n$ is a stopping time. Fix $0\le s\le t$, we wish to show that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t\wedge T}|\mathcal{F_s}\right]\le X_s
$$
almost surely. Similarly define
$$
t_n = \inf\left\{u\in D_n; u\ge t\right\} \ge t_{n+1}\ge\cdots
$$
and
$$
s_n = \inf\left\{u\in D_n; u\ge s\right\} \ge s_{n+1}\ge\cdots
$$
It follows from the discrete time optional sampling theorem that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t_n\wedge T_n}|\mathcal{F}_{s_m}\right] \le X_{s_m \wedge T_n}
$$
for any integers $m\ge n$. Letting $m\to\infty$, we have $s_m \to s$ decreasing and $\mathcal{F}_{s_m}\to\mathcal{F}_s$. By Lévy's Downward theorem and the continuity of process $X$, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t_n\wedge T_n}|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right] \le X_{s_m \wedge T_n}
$$
Observe that $(X_{t_n\wedge T_n},\mathcal{F}_{t_n\wedge T_n})$ is a *backward martingale*, whence it is uniformly integrable. Letting $n\to\infty$, we arrive at
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[X_{t\wedge T}|\mathcal{F}_{s}\right] \le X_{s\wedge T}.
$$
This completes the proof.

Comment: Why downvote? I think this solution is good...

Comment: There are down-voting trolls all over the place... This week-end I asked a question about NoSQL databases and got down-voted twice. Thank you for your support though