# Brownian motion: how is DCT for conditional expectation applied on this stopped martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, proof-explanation, conditional-expectation, martingales, stopping-times

I'm reading a theorem at page $43$ of these [notes](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/sc2_final.pdf), i.e.,

---

> **Proposition 7.12.** Let $M$ be a continuous local martingale with respect to a filtration $\left(\mathcal{F}_t, t \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$ such that
> $$
> M_0=\begin{array}{ll}
> 0 & \text { a.s }
> \end{array} \text { and } \lim _{t \rightarrow \infty}\langle M\rangle_t=\infty \quad \text { a.s. }
> $$
>
> Let us also define
> $$
> \tau(s)=\inf \left\{t>0:\langle M\rangle_t \geq s\right\},
> \quad B_s=M_{\tau(s)}, \quad \mathcal{G}_s=\mathcal{F}_{\tau(s)}.
> $$
>
> Then $B$ is a standard Brownian motion with respect to $\left(\mathcal{G}_s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.

**Proof.** As already mentioned, the idea is to use Lévy's theorem, i.e., to show that

- (i) $B$ has continuous trajectories.
- (ii) $B$ is a local martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{G}_s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.
- (iii) $\langle B\rangle_s=s$, i.e., $\left(B_s^2-s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$is a local martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{G}_s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.

Let us verify these three statements.

- (i) As $M$ is continuous, $t \rightarrow\langle M\rangle_t$ is also continuous. Moreover, if $\langle M\rangle$ is constant on some interval, then $M$ also is, so the function $s \mapsto B_s=M_{\tau(s)}$ is continuous.
- (ii) Let $\tau_n=\inf \left\{t>0:\left|M_t\right| \geq n\right\}, n \geq 1$. For each $n, M^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale such that
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(\sup _{t \in[0, T]}\left|M_{t \wedge \tau_n}\right|^2\right)<\infty, \quad \forall T>0,
  $$
  so by the optional stopping theorem (version 2), we have
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(M_{\tau\left(s_2\right) \wedge \tau_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau\left(s_1\right)}\right)=M_{\tau\left(s_1\right) \wedge \tau_n} \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \forall s_2>s_1 \geq 0 .
  $$
  By the **dominated convergence theorem** (and **some details**), this implies that
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(M_{\tau\left(s_2\right)} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau\left(s_1\right)}\right)=M_{\tau\left(s_1\right)} \quad \text { a.s. }
  \quad \quad  (\star)
  $$
  i.e.,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(B_{s_2} \mid \mathcal{G}_{s_1}\right)=B_{s_1} \quad \text { a.s. }
  $$
  i.e., $B$ is a martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{G}_s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.
- (iii) Let $X_t=M_t^2-\langle M\rangle_t$. By assumption, $X^{\tau_n}$ is a martingale $\forall n$, so
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(X_{\tau\left(s_2\right) \wedge \tau_n} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau\left(s_1\right)}\right)=X_{\tau\left(s_1\right) \wedge \tau_n} \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \forall s_2>s_1 \geq 0
  $$
  Then again by the dominated convergence theorem (and some details), we obtain that
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(X_{\tau\left(s_2\right)} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau\left(s_1\right)}\right)=X_{\tau\left(s_1\right)} \quad \text { a.s. }
  $$
  i.e.,
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(M_{\tau\left(s_2\right)}^2-\langle M\rangle_{\tau\left(s_2\right)} \mid \mathcal{F}_{\tau\left(s_1\right)}\right)=M_{\tau\left(s_1\right)}^2-\langle M\rangle_{\tau\left(s_1\right)} \quad \text { a.s. }
  $$
  As $\langle M\rangle_{\tau(s)}=s$ by definition, we obtain:
  $$
  \mathbb{E}\left(B_{s_2}^2-s_2 \mid \mathcal{G}_{s_1}\right)=B_{s_1}^2-s_1 \quad a . s ., \quad \forall s_2>s_1 \geq 0
  $$
  i.e., $\left(B_s^2-s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$is a martingale with respect to $\left(\mathcal{G}_s, s \in \mathbb{R}_{+}\right)$.

---

**My understanding** I have a problem understanding how $(\star)$ is obtained. To apply dominated convergence theorem, we need
$$
|M_{\tau\left(s_2\right) \wedge \tau_n}| \le Z \quad \text{a.s.} \quad \forall n\in \mathbb N,
$$
for some integrable random variable $Z$. I could not see how to have such $Z$.

> Could you elaborate on how DCT is applied to get $(\star)$.

Comment: $\vert M_t\vert\le n$ for all $t\le\tau_n$, a.s., by definition of $\tau_n$. So $Z=n$.

Comment: @Will but we take the limit $n \to \infty$...

Comment: Oh you need an upper bound independent of $n$ ok sorry

Comment: $\tau_n$ goes to $+\infty$ with $n$. So $X_{\tau(s_1)\wedge\tau_n}$ converges almost surely to $X_{\tau(s_1)}$. And $X$ is a uniformly integrable martingale, so so is $X^{\tau(s_2)}$, hence $X_{\tau(s_2)\wedge\tau_n}$ converges in $L^1$ to $X_{\tau(s_2)}$ as $n\to+\infty$. This is a way to show $(\star)$.

Comment: Actually I meant $M$ instead of $X$, but it is true for both.

Comment: @Will I have posted my attempt below. Could you have a check on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [Vitali's convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_convergence_theorem?useskin=vector), it suffices to show that $( M_{\tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n}, n \in \mathbb N)$ is uniformly integrable. By [OST](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096859/proof-that-a-stopped-continuous-time-martingale-is-a-martingale?rq=1), $( M_{t \wedge \tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n}, t \ge 0)$ is a martingale. By Doob's maximal inequality,
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E \big [ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} | M_{s \wedge \tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} |^2 \big ] &\le 4 \mathbb E [ | M_{t \wedge \tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} |^2 ] \\
&= 4 \mathbb E [ \langle M \rangle_{t \wedge \tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} ] \\
&\le 4 \mathbb E [ \langle M \rangle_{\tau (s_2)} ] = 4 s_2.
\end{align}
$$

By monotone convergence thereom,
$$
\mathbb E \big [ \sup_{s \in [0, \infty)} | M_{s \wedge \tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} |^2 \big ] \le 4 s_2.
$$

Notice that
$$
| M_{\tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} |^2 \le \sup_{s \in [0, \infty)} | M_{s \wedge \tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} |^2.
$$

Hence
$$
\mathbb E \big [ | M_{\tau (s_2) \wedge \tau_n} |^2 \big ] \le 4 s_2 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb N.
$$

The claim then follows from below result (taken from these [notes](https://web.math.ku.dk/noter/filer/vidsand12.pdf)), i.e.,

> **Example 5.4.3.** Let $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of real random variables. If $\sup _{i \in I} \mathbb E [ |X_i|^r ] < \infty$ for some $r>1$, then $(X_i)$ is uniformly integrable.

Comment: Looks correct to me

Comment: @Will Thank you so much for your verification!