# Let $M$ be a continuous martingale, $r >0$, and $\tau := \inf \{t \ge 0 : \langle M \rangle_t \ge r \}$. Then $M_\tau$ is square-integrable

Tags: probability-theory, solution-verification, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F, \mathbb P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal G = (\mathcal G_t, t \ge 0)$ a filtration. Let $M$ be a real-valued continuous martingale w.r.t. $\mathcal G$ such that
$$
(\star) \quad M_0 = 0
\quad \text{and} \quad (\star \star) \quad
\lim_{t \to \infty} \langle M \rangle_t=\infty.
$$

Fix $r >0$ and define a stopping time $\tau := \inf \{t \ge 0 : \langle M \rangle_t \ge r \}$. By $(\star \star)$, we have $\tau$ is finite. I would like to prove that

> **Theorem** $M_\tau$ is square-integrable.

Could you have a check on my below attempt?

---

**Proof** By [OST](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1096859/proof-that-a-stopped-continuous-time-martingale-is-a-martingale?rq=1), $M^\tau = (M_{t \wedge \tau}, t \ge 0)$ is a martingale. We define a process $X$ by $X_t := M_t^2 - \langle M \rangle_t$ for all $t \ge0$. Then $X$ and thus $X^\tau$ are martingales. By $(\star)$, we have $X^\tau_0=0$. Hence
$$
\mathbb E [X_{t \wedge \tau}] = \mathbb E [ |M_{t \wedge \tau}|^2 - \langle M \rangle_{t \wedge \tau} ]  = 0.
$$

We have $\mathbb E [ \langle M \rangle_{t \wedge \tau} ] \le \mathbb E [ \langle M \rangle_{\tau} ]$. Because $M$ and thus $\langle M \rangle$ have continuous sample paths, we get $\mathbb E [ \langle M \rangle_{\tau} ] = r$. Hence
$$
\mathbb E [ |M_{t \wedge \tau}|^2 ] = \mathbb E [ \langle M \rangle_{t \wedge \tau} ] \le r.
$$

By Doob's maximal inequality,
$$
\mathbb E \big [ \sup_{s \in [0, t]} | M_{s \wedge \tau} |^2 \big ] \le 4 \mathbb E [ | M_{t \wedge \tau} |^2 ] \le 4 r.
$$

By monotone convergence theorem,
$$
\mathbb E \big [ \sup_{s \in [0, \infty)} | M_{s \wedge \tau} |^2 \big ] \le 4r.
$$

Clearly,
$$
| M_{\tau} |^2 \le \sup_{s \in [0, \infty)} | M_{s \wedge \tau} |^2.
$$

Hence $\mathbb E [ | M_{\tau} |^2 ] \le4r$. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct.  One could also use Fatou's lemma for a slightly more direct proof and a tighter bound: After showing $\mathbb{E}[|M_{t \wedge \tau}|^2] \le r$, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|M_\tau|^2] &= \mathbb{E}\left[\liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} |M_{t \wedge \tau}|^2\right] \\
&\le \liminf_{t \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{E}\left[|M_{t \wedge \tau}|^2\right] \\
&\le r\end{align*}.

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification! Can we weaken the conditions $(\star)$ or $(\star\star)$?

Comment: @Analyst The condition $M_0 = 0$ can be replaced with $M_0 \in L^2$.  The condition $\langle M \rangle_t \rightarrow \infty$ is also unnecessary because $\langle M \rangle_{t \wedge \tau} \le r$ holds regardless of whether $\tau$ is finite or not, but dropping this condition requires showing that $\{\omega: \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} M_t \text{ exists }\} \subseteq \{\omega : \lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} \langle M \rangle_t < \infty\}$ a.s.  See Proposition 4.1.23 in Revuz and Yor's _Continuous Martingales and Brownian Motion_